# Hide the tree menu at a certain depth

Tags: javascript, jquery, tree

I have created this piece of js purely for learning purposes and I was hoping you could code review to see any mistakes / improvements I can make.

Basically I have a tree structure and I will use the depth variable to work out what level of the menu I will display.

Here is the code example: http://jsfiddle.net/nqGbw/5/

**HTML**

```
The Tree
<ul>
    <li> <a href="?1">Root</a>
        <ul>
            <li> <a href="?2">Folder 1</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="?3">Folder 1.1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="?4">Folder 1.2</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li> <a href="?5">Folder 2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="?6">Folder 2.1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li> <a href="?7">Folder 2.2</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="?8">Folder 2.2.1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="?8">Folder 2.2.2</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="?9">Folder 2.2.3</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
var calcDepth = function (root) {
    var $parent = $(root).parents('ul');
    var depth = 0;
    while ($parent.length > 0) {
        $parent = $parent.parents('ul');
        depth += 1;
    }
    return depth;
};


var func = function (rootUL, maxDepth) {
    var selectedUL = rootUL;
    $(selectedUL.children('li')).each(function () {
        var Me = $(this);
        if (calcDepth(Me.parent()) == maxDepth) {
            Me.hide();
        }
        if (Me.children('ul').length > 0) {
            var selectedUL = Me.children('ul');
            func(selectedUL, maxDepth);
        }
    });
};
var depth = 2; //Change this to set the depth of the menu
var selectedUL = $("ul");
func(selectedUL, depth);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be much easier just to let the CSS selector engine select the elements to hide:

```
var hideDepth = function(root, depth) {
   root.find('ul').show(); // Make sure all sublists are visible 
   var selector = Array(depth + 1).join(' > li > ul'); // Repeat string
   root.find(selector).hide();
}

var depth = 2; 
var selectedUL = $("#tree");

hideDepth(selectedUL, depth);
```

NOTE: Add the id `tree` to the top level `ul`. Your selector `$('ul')`selects all lists in the document, not just the top one, so your code was unnecessarily called repeatedly for each sub list.

For the string repeating see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877475/repeat-character-n-times.